# How to set an array of multiple data as a state

Tags: react-native, axios

So basically I want to be able to collect all the values from multiple inputs and set that array as a state. Here is what I am currently working with:

```
this.state.basket.map(b => {
  return (
    <View>
      <InputSpinner
        style={styles.spinnerQty}
        max={50}
        min={1}
        step={1}
        rounded={false}
        showBorder
        colorMax={"#2a292d"}
        colorMin={"#2a292d"}
        value={b.qty}
        onChange={num => {
          this.setState({ popUpQty: num });
        }}
      />

      <View style={styles.hrLine}></View>
    </View>
  );
});
```

So I am iterating my `basket` and setting a spinner with a value from axios output. So there are now multiple `InputSpinner` with multiple values.
My question is, how can I collect all the values of the `onChange`, and push it to an array which will eventually become a state. Something like `QuantityState: []` would be the values of all the `InputSpinner`. Hope that made sense. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

PS. InputSpinner is an npm package from [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-input-spinner).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Through this code you can dynamically add/update onChange number on it's particular array instance. **num** key will be added when a particular onChange trigger so at the end you will get its values which placed on it's index and if key not found that means onChange never triggered for that index

```
state = {
        spinnerData : {},
        basket: []
    }



    this.state.basket.map((b, index) => {
      return (
        <View>
          <InputSpinner
            style={styles.spinnerQty}
            max={50}
            min={1}
            step={1}
            rounded={false}
            showBorder
            colorMax={"#2a292d"}
            colorMin={"#2a292d"}
            value={b.qty}
            onChange={num => {
              const newbasket = [...this.state.basket];
              newbasket[index]["num"] = num;
              this.setState({ basket:newbasket });
            }}
          />

          <View style={styles.hrLine}></View>
        </View>
      );
    });
```

Comment: I am currently unable to test the code but I had some questions. My basket state contains an array of some other data. I want to set the onChange array to some other state. So I can change the basket state in your answer to say “qtyState” and it would still work yes?

Comment: Yes this will work if you implement as I answered. This will add "num" key dynamically in every object of basket array. At the end you will get the onChange values

Comment: Its giving syntax errors. Like `basket[index]` my IDE is suggesting to put colon in between basket and [index]. And near `num` `,` expected and so on

Comment: Try updating to this **this.setState({ basket[index]["num"]: num });** and run the code by ignoring the IDE suggestions.

Comment: Unexpected token, expected "," near `basket[index]` in between basket and index

Comment: Unexpected token, expected ";". This was near `newbasket[index]["num"]: num;` where ["num"]:num. Colon is giving error

Comment: Sorry it was error. check and try again. I have updated again

Comment: Ok this works perfectly but there is another issue. In axios I am doing this. `axios.post('http://something.com/basket/addToOrder/', {
            test: this.state.basket.qty,

        })` test returns null. I wanted actually to be able to get those in my laravel backend only qty from basket. I am updating qty (instead of num as in your example). So how do I take only qty in `test: this.state.basket.qty`

Comment: To get qty map your `basket` variable. `test: this.state.basket.map((item) => item.qty)`

Comment: Try this two line of code before sending data to axios. **let result = this.state.basket.map(b => b.qty);
const qtyData = JSON.stringify(result);** then add **qtyData** to test param like **axios.post('http://something.com/basket/addToOrder/', 
 { test:qtyData }
 )**